# Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx is denied while running task in AWS ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

Following is the error coming in running task of AWS ECS cluster.

com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXQueue is denied. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXXXX-XXX-XX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX; Proxy: null)

**As per the initial analysis , I have modified the access policy of queue and the iam role of ecs task as follows**

```
Access policy of SQS

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:root"
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXXXXXX/xxxxxx-exec-role"         ,
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXXXXXX/xxxxxx-deploy-role",
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXXXXXXX/xxxxxx-task-role",
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sqs:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also added below statement to all the above mentioned IAM role who are running the task in the AWS ECS as follows

```
Statement added in IAM roles associated with AWS ECS Task: 

{
      "Action": [
        "sqs:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_NUMBER_HERE:xxx*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

**please let me know in case if I am missing anything or if you have resolved such issues before**

Comment: What are ecs roles?

Comment: @Marcin what do you means by ecs roles?

Comment: What is `ECE*` supposed to be in the IAM policy you posted? What is `ECE`?

Comment: @Marcin oh its identifier for app , I removed it from question. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the EC2 container instance role in the SQS access policy as below. No need to add ECS execution or task or deploy role as mentioned in the question.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```